# What is causing this Runtime.ExitError on AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, aws-lambda

I'm trying to test a function on Lambda, but when I test it i get a **Runtime.ExitError**:

What would be the cause?

```
{"errorType": "Runtime.ExitError", "errorMessage": "RequestId:
 0dfeb7be-012d-43b7-8674-665bfd8b2bc2 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 7" }
```

> ask/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:364:18)","    at
> Request.callListeners
> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)","
> at Request.emit
> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)","
> at Request.emit
> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)","    at
> Request.transition
> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)","    at
> AcceptorStateMachine.runTo
> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)","    at
> /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10","    at
> Request.
> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)"],"message":"Could
> not create table (Meals): User:
> arn:aws:sts::929545228810:assumed-role/homeAssistTemp-role-rz5qgsmq/homeAssistTemp
> is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:CreateTable on resource:
> arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:929545228810:table/Meals","time":"2019-09-26T18:02:51.854Z"}
> 2019-09-26T18:02:51.931Z  e3d534bb-abd8-4b49-a628-2ec5c6193ec1    INFO    Uncaught
> exception: AskSdk.DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter Error: Could not create
> table (Meals): User:
> arn:aws:sts::929545228810:assumed-role/homeAssistTemp-role-rz5qgsmq/homeAssistTemp
> is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:CreateTable on resource:
> arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:929545228810:table/Meals
> AskSdk.DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter Error: Could not create table
> (Meals): User:
> arn:aws:sts::929545228810:assumed-role/homeAssistTemp-role-rz5qgsmq/homeAssistTemp
> is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:CreateTable on resource:
> arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:929545228810:table/Meals
> at Object.createAskSdkError (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/util/AskSdkUtils.js:22:17)
> at Response. (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-dynamodb-persistence-adapter/dist/attributes/persistence/DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter.js:88:42)
> at Request. (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:364:18)
> at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
> at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
> at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
> at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
> at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
> at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
> at Request. (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
> /var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-v1adapter/dist/adapter.js:275
> throw err;
> ^
>
> AskSdk.DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter Error: Could not create table
> (Meals): User:
> arn:aws:sts::929545228810:assumed-role/homeAssistTemp-role-rz5qgsmq/homeAssistTemp
> is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:CreateTable on resource:
> arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:929545228810:table/Meals
> at Object.createAskSdkError (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/util/AskSdkUtils.js:22:17)
> at Response. (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-dynamodb-persistence-adapter/dist/attributes/persistence/DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter.js:88:42)
> at Request. (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:364:18)
> at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
> at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
> at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
> at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
> at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
> at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
> at Request. (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9) END RequestId:
> e3d534bb-abd8-4b49-a628-2ec5c6193ec1 REPORT RequestId:
> e3d534bb-abd8-4b49-a628-2ec5c6193ec1  Duration: 1013.44 ms    Billed
> Duration: 1100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 97 MB  Init
> Duration: 513.63 ms    RequestId: e3d534bb-abd8-4b49-a628-2ec5c6193ec1
> Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 7 Runtime.ExitError

Comment: Can you verify your function is not exceeding timeout value and memory allocated?

Comment: What do the CloudWatch logs say?

Comment: Assuming this is a NodeJS lambda, exit code 7 is `Internal Exception Handler Run-Time Failure`.  In other words, you have an uncaught exception.  Check your cloudwatch logs for more details.

Comment: I've added the log. Maybe there's a clear error

Comment: the try, catch solved that issue. Thanks Anon

Answer (score 16):

I found this page in researching and thought I'd post my issue / solution. Wasn't getting exactly exit code 7, but specifically:

```
Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed Runtime.ExitError
```

No other errors, logs, etc. Previous line gave away the solution:

```
Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 1024 MB
```

Was running out of memory on my Lambda function execution. Upped the max memory, and the issue was resolved. Memory is a good thing to check if you see Runtime.ExitError.

Comment: earlier I used to see timeout error when set max to 15mins for lambda, then for it to do the process faster, I increased from 128 mb to 256 mb now the thing is I don't see the timeout but see frequent Runtime.ExitError but this error comes up within 4mins of execution itself. Any idea about why I didn't get it earlier and just timeout where as now I am seeing memory issue?

Answer (score 1):

"Assuming this is a NodeJS lambda, exit code 7 is Internal Exception Handler Run-Time Failure. In other words, you have an uncaught exception. Check your cloudwatch logs for more details." – Anon Coward

wrapping the code in the exports.handler with a try-catch solved my issue

Comment: Huh. Well, that’s a first.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like permissions to me:

Could not create table (Meals): User: **arn:aws:sts::929545228810:assumed-role/homeAssistTemp-role-rz5qgsmq/homeAssistTemp** is not authorized to perform: **dynamodb:CreateTable** on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:929545228810:table/Meals

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a Node.js Lambda with an ENV variable `NODE_OPTIONS` requiring a module that was not found `-r module`

Answer (score 0):

You can revisit your serverless.yaml file. This could be because of many things but in my case, the lambda handler was not imported correctly in serverless.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when running a Docker container on Lambda.  The problem was the Docker container had `$HOME` as `/root` but Lambda runs as an unprivileged user, so it had no write access to `/root`.

This is important because Lambda uses `npx` (which is the same as `npm exec`) to start the [runtime interface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda-ric), and the first thing NPM does is look in `$HOME/.npm`.  So if that folder is not writable, the Lambda will fail to start.

I could see this was the problem because the CloudWatch logs for the Lambda were telling me there was a permissions error on `/root/.npm`.  It told me to run `chmod` to fix it, but even `chmod 777` did not work.

The solution in my case was to add the line `ENV HOME /tmp` to the Dockerfile, to move the home directory to `/tmp` which is writable by the user the Lambda runs as.