Conversion of PDF file to PNGs using AWS Lambda gets terminated by the runtime
I want to process large pdf file (800 pages) to png file using AWS Lambda and Python.
Could you please suggest me some approaches or code for Lambda function.
I tried to convert multipage PDF to PNG. However I'm getting a runtime exit error for PDFs with at least 50 pages.
import json
import boto3
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import logging
import os
from datetime import datetime
import fitz
import urllib.parse

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Initialize AWS clients
lambda_client = boto3.client("lambda")
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
s3 = boto3.client("s3")

# Specify the DynamoDB table name
TABLE_NAME = "XYZ"


# Function to update document status in DynamoDB
def update_document_status(batch_id, status, stage):
    try:
        doc_status_table_name = dynamodb.Table(TABLE_NAME)
        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        update_expression = (
            "SET #status = :status, #stage = :stage, #updated_date = :updated_date"
        )
        expression_attribute_names = {
            "#status": "status",
            "#stage": "stage",
            "#updated_date": "updated_date",
        }
        expression_attribute_values = {
            ":status": status,
            ":stage": stage,
            ":updated_date": current_time,
        }

        # If the status is either completed or failed, update end_time and update_time
        if status in ["completed", "failed"]:
            update_expression += ", #end_time = :end_time, #update_time = :update_time"
            expression_attribute_names["#end_time"] = "end_time"
            expression_attribute_names["#update_time"] = "update_time"
            expression_attribute_values[":end_time"] = current_time
            expression_attribute_values[":update_time"] = current_time

        response = doc_status_table_name.update_item(
            Key={"batch_id": batch_id},
            UpdateExpression=update_expression,
            ExpressionAttributeNames=expression_attribute_names,
            ExpressionAttributeValues=expression_attribute_values,
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW",
        )
        logger.info("UpdateItem succeeded: %s", response)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error updating document status: %s", e)
        raise


# Function to convert multi-page TIFF file to PNG
def convert_multi_page_tiff_to_png(tiff_file):
    try:
        png_images = []
        with Image.open(tiff_file) as img:
            if img.n_frames > 1:
                for i in range(img.n_frames):
                    img.seek(i)
                    png_bytes = BytesIO()
                    img.save(png_bytes, format="PNG")
                    png_images.append(png_bytes.getvalue())
            else:
                # For single-page TIFF, directly convert it to PNG
                png_bytes = BytesIO()
                img.save(png_bytes, format="PNG")
                png_images.append(png_bytes.getvalue())
        return png_images
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error converting multi-page TIFF to PNG: {e}")
        raise


# Function to convert multi-page PDF file to PNG
def convert_multi_page_pdf_to_png(pdf_data):
    try:
        png_images = []
        pdf_file = fitz.open(stream=pdf_data, filetype='pdf')
        for i in range(len(pdf_file)):
            pix = pdf_file[i].get_pixmap()

            img = Image.frombytes("RGB", [pix.width, pix.height], pix.samples)
            png_bio = BytesIO()
            img.save(png_bio, format='PNG')

            png_images.append(png_bio.getvalue())            
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error converting multi-page PDF to PNG: {e}")
        raise
    
    return png_images

def process_zip_file(filepath):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filepath, 'r') as zip_ref:
        for filename in zip_ref.namelist():
            print(f"processing file: {filename}")
            if filename.endswith('.tif') or filename.endswith('.tiff'):
                tiff_data = zip_ref.read(filename)
                png_images = convert_multi_page_tiff_to_png(tiff_data)
                
                # Only needed for local testing
                save_images(png_images, filename)
            elif filename.endswith('.pdf'):
                pdf_data = zip_ref.read(filename)
                png_images = convert_multi_page_pdf_to_png(pdf_data)
                
                # Only needed for local testing
                save_images(png_images, filename)
            else:
                print(f"Skipping processing of unsupported file format: {filename}")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        batch_id = None
        logger.info("Received Event: %s", json.dumps(event, indent=2))

        folder_name = event.get("FILENAME")

        if folder_name is None:
            logger.error("Directory name not found in the event.")
            raise ValueError("Directory name not found in the event.")

        if not isinstance(folder_name, str):
            logger.error("Directory name is not a string.")
            raise ValueError("Directory name is not a string.")

        logger.info(f"Directory Name: {folder_name}")

        bucket_name = "cnc-aws-ecs-mecc-dev-doc-processing-v2"

        response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=folder_name)

        json_file_key = None
        matching_zip_file_key = None

        for obj in response.get("Contents", []):
            file_key = obj["Key"]
            logger.info(f"Processing file: {file_key}")

            if file_key.endswith(".json") and file_key.startswith(folder_name):
                json_file_key = file_key
            elif file_key.endswith(".zip") and file_key.startswith(folder_name):
                matching_zip_file_key = file_key

        logger.info(f"JSON file key: {json_file_key}")
        logger.info(f"Matching ZIP file key: {matching_zip_file_key}")

        if json_file_key is not None and matching_zip_file_key is not None:
            try:
                response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=json_file_key)
                data = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
                batch_id = data['SCANMETADATA']['batchid']
                logger.info("Batch ID: %s", batch_id)

                zip_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=matching_zip_file_key)

                update_document_status(batch_id, "inprogress", "Image Conversion")

                pdf_data = zip_obj['Body'].read()  # Read PDF data from the ZIP file

                process_zip_file(pdf_data)  # Pass pdf_data to the function

                update_document_status(batch_id, "completed", "Image Conversion")

                s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=json_file_key)
                logger.info(
                    "JSON file removed from original location: %s", json_file_key
                )

                s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=matching_zip_file_key)
                logger.info("Original ZIP file deleted: %s", matching_zip_file_key)

                if json_file_key.startswith(folder_name):
                    s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=folder_name + "/")
                    logger.info("Directory removed: %s", folder_name)

                return event, folder_name

            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error processing ZIP file {matching_zip_file_key}: {e}")
                update_document_status(batch_id, "error", "Image Conversion")
                raise e
        else:
            logger.error("Both JSON and matching ZIP files are not found.")
            raise Exception("Both JSON and matching ZIP files are not found.")

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error: {e}")
        if batch_id:
            update_document_status(batch_id, "failed", "Image Conversion")
        raise e


Error:
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: ddb8e3d0-0ab5-4462-ab8f-ae7797fb93ad Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed"
}


It's possible out of memory. You may need to increase your lambda memory. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68185742/7035646]

Can you please explain how to do it in python aws lambda

@Iwin  can you please explain in my case how to resolve it my lambda max time 15 mns set already. Help me to resolve the issue

As suggested earlier test with max RAM (see here) and progressively larger PDF files, say 10 pages, 25 pages, 50 pages, 100 pages to determine what amount of resource (RAM and execution time) is actually required.

How are you provisioning the Lambda function? Are you using SAM, CDK, Terraform or manual provisioning via the AWS Console?

Your Lambda function might be running out of RAM because your code is pushing all the images into a memory-based array. This could be the reason that the application got terminated by the runtime.
Approach A:
You will have to set the MemorySize configuration of your function to a higher value as a quick but not scalable solution with least effort required. PS. You'll get more vCPUs as well when you allocate higher levels of memory to your function.
Approach B
If the problem still persists, you may want to consider saving your images to the ephemeral storage of the function instead of holding them in your function's memory (Replace the line of code where you store the images inside the array with code that will store the images into /tmp instead).
Approach C:
Using approach B will allow you to process even larger PDFs with more pages but will not be the most scalable solution. You can consider splitting the processing of image snapshots into multiple functions to achieve lower overall processing time and far higher scalability for the largest PDFs.

Make a lambda function (Segmenter) that will evaluate how many pages exists inside a PDF. This function will then divide the number of pages by the number of parallelism you'd like to achieve (EG. 800 pages could be divided by 8).
Kickstart the image processing batches by using SQS or EventBridge and providing the segment information plus the PDF information as message.
Build a segment processor function that will perform the actual conversion of the PDF pages into images under the segment only. This should be the function that reacts to the messsages sent over by the segmenter function.
Once all the images are completed, you can trigger a final function that will combine the output of the segment processing functions.

PS: Max execution time in seconds is more concerned with the time it takes before Lambda service reclaims your execution environment and will not solve your problem if you've already maxed it out.
